# Create loop or function that calculates through every observation and performs another calculation based off the result of the first calculation

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a vector called time:
`Time <- c(2.444582, 2.445613, 2.446644, 2.447675, 2.448706, 2.449737, 2.769358, 2.770389, 2.771420, 2.772451, 2.773482, 2.774513, 2.775544, 2.776575, 2.777606, 3.087606, 3.093759, 3.099134, 3.100493, 3.478295, 3.484896, 3.482309)`

I want to create a loop or function that subtracts every observation from the previous one, for example: 2.445613-2.444582, 2.446644-2.445613, 2.447675-2.446644 etc. Then if the difference between each observation is greater than 0.2 (i.e 2.769358-2.448706 = 0.320), I want to get the difference between the lesser number and the first number in that sequence (i.e. 2.449737-2.444582, 2.777606-2.769358, 3.100493-3.087606) and the difference from the last number in the vector and the first number in the particular sequence (i.e. 3.482309-3.478295)

My desired output from this Time vector would be: 0.005155, 0.008248, 0.012887, 0.004014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way without loops :

We first get the positions where the difference between current observation and the previous one is greater than 0.2. We then create index using this position to subset values from `Time` vector.

```
inds <- which(diff(Time) > 0.2)
Time[c(inds, length(Time))] - Time[c(1, inds + 1)]
#[1] 0.005155 0.008248 0.012887 0.004014
```

Comment: when I run that code inds is an integer(empty) and the Time[c(inds, length(Time))] - Time[c(1, inds + 1)] returns a 10

Comment: @mpvalenc Are you using the same `Time` that you have shared in the post? Using that I get `inds` as `6 15 19`.

Comment: yes sorry it worked when I used the same Time that I shared in the post, but in my actual Time vector in my code, its a subset to meet the logical criteria that I want so my row numbers are not in order (i.e. rownumbers 810-922, 1232-1401, 1705-1883) any work around this?

Comment: What do you mean by not in order? Do you have `NA` values? Can you create an example which represents your actual data so that it is easier to help?

Comment: I had to filter my data to get the Time vector that I wanted (i.e. get the time when the numbers in the corresponding col were negative) and select the Time col. Here is my code to do so:FT <- Hop_L_Trial1[Hop_L_Trial1$FzR<=0, ] %>%select(Time) Now my FT is what I put in place into your code where you put "Time". 2.444582 is the first time observation where FzR is <= 0, however it isn't row 1 because I filtered, its row 810 in my FT dataframe

Comment: rownames(Hop_L_Trial1_FT) <- NULL, got the rownumbers ordered like that. But inds is still integer (empty)

Comment: Figured it out,  inds <- which(diff(Hop_L_Trial1_FT$Time) > 0.2)
    Hop_L_Trial1_FT$Time[c(inds, length(Hop_L_Trial1_FT$Time))] - Hop_L_Trial1_FT$Time[c(1, inds + 1)] thank you again

Comment: Code is working, but can you explain: Time[c(inds, length(Time))] - Time[c(1, inds + 1)] from my understanding we found the indices where the difference from all consecutive values were greater than 0.2, then I get lost on how exactly you're indexing in the next line of code.

Comment: `inds` are all the position where the difference is greater than 0.2 whereas `inds + 1` is the next index. If you break this down you'll see that we subtract position `6 - 1`, `15-7`,`19-16` and `22-20`. The values 7, 16 and 20 are `inds + 1`.